# How to solve route not defined

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I run my program, I get an error "Route [userproductss.prdtview] not defined. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\E-commerce\resources\views\layouts\includes\top.blade.php)". The code is given below

blade:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <li><a href="#">{{$category->cat_name}}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            @foreach($subcat as $sub_cat)
            @if($sub_cat->cat_id == $category->id)
            <li><a href="{{ route('userproduct.prdtview',$sub_cat->id) }}"><?php echo $sub_cat->sub_cat_name; ?></a></li>
            @endif
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
    @endforeach                        
</ul>
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('userproduct', 'UserProductController');
```

controller:

```
public function prdtview($id)
{
    $data=DB::select('select category.cat_name,product_images.prdt_image,product.prdt_name,product.actual_price from product INNER JOIN category on product.catid = category.id INNER JOIN product_images on product.id = product_images.prdt_id where product.sub_cat_id = $id ');
    return view("frontend.product",[
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Define a route with that name. Use `php artisan route:list` to list your routes & names

Comment: @Muhammad `get` is not a method name handled by resource controllers though

Comment: "_Route [userproductss.prdtview]_" ... `userproductss` ... is that a typo?

Comment: @kerbh0lz, Its been years I did not use laravel :D, I think its `index`

Comment: change `{{ route('userproduct.prdtview',$sub_cat->id) }}` to `{{ route('userproduct.show',$sub_cat->id) }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory you have not defined the route for your `prdtview` function.
Remember whenever you make a resource controller and defines its route then the following function with its routes are automatically created.

```
  /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */



    public function index()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
```

For any other method you want your route to use, then you have to make one method and must define a route for it like for your `prdtview` function you have to explicitly define a route for example.

```
Route::get('/prdtview/{id}','UserProductController@prdtview')->name('userproduct.prdtview);
```

Now when the request will hit to this route it will be forwarded to your `prdtview` function.

You can now call your route in blade like

```
route('userproduct.prdtview', ['id' => $sub_cat->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel defines default route names when you're using `resource`

You can find more detail in here; https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers